# Pandas: Group by a column that meets a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a data set with three colums: rating , breed, and dog.

```
import pandas as pd
dogs = {'breed': ['Chihuahua', 'Chihuahua', 'Dalmatian', 'Sphynx'],
        'dog': [True, True, True, False],
        'rating': [8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 7.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dogs)
```

I would like to calculate the **mean** rating per breed where dog is True. This would be the expected:

```
  breed     rating
0 Chihuahua 8.5   
1 Dalmatian 10.0
```

This has been my attempt:

```
df.groupby('breed')['rating'].mean().where(dog == True)
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
NameError: name 'dog' is not defined
```

But when I try add the `where` condition I only get errors. Can anyone advise a solution? TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you groupby and select a column, your `dog` column doesn't exist anymore in the context you have selected (and even if it did you are not accessing it correctly).

Filter your dataframe first, *then* use **`groupby`** with **`mean`**

```
df[df.dog].groupby('breed')['rating'].mean().reset_index()

       breed  rating
0  Chihuahua     8.5
1  Dalmatian    10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to make `dog` one of your grouper keys. Then filter by `dog` in a separate step. This is more efficient if you do not want to lose aggregated data for non-dogs.

```
res = df.groupby(['dog', 'breed'])['rating'].mean().reset_index()

print(res)

     dog      breed  rating
0  False     Sphynx     7.0
1   True  Chihuahua     8.5
2   True  Dalmatian    10.0

print(res[res['dog']])

    dog      breed  rating
1  True  Chihuahua     8.5
2  True  Dalmatian    10.0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It's an interesting approach as well.