# Using pandas groupby and numpy where together in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am a newbie to python!

I need to use pd.groupby() function under np.where().

Below is the screen capture of my data set:

[image]

Following is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/gautam/Desktop/data.csv")
df.head()

grouped = df.groupby('Occupation')['Emp_Code'].count() #Calculating Count of Employees by Occupation

np.where(df['Gender']=='M', df.groupby('Occupation')['Emp_Code'].count()/grouped*100,0)
```

Basically I need to calculate the male ratio per occupation.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add your data as text, not as picture.

Comment: `df['Gender'].eq('M').gropuby(df['Occupation']).mean()`.

Comment: `df.groupby('Occupation')['Gender'].value_counts(normalize=True)`

Comment: related : [Pandas: Group by a column that meets a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662469/pandas-group-by-a-column-that-meets-a-condition)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? You write _I need to use pd.groupby() function under np.where()_, but your code appears to be doing that already.

Comment: AMC, it's throwing  ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (943,) (21,) ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with mean of boolean mask, so get `Series` with same size like original, so possible pass to `np.where` for new column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Occupation':list('dddeee'),
         'Emp_Code':list('aabbcc'),
         'Gender':list('MFMFMF')
})
print (df)
  Occupation Emp_Code Gender
0          d        a      M
1          d        a      F
2          d        b      M
3          e        b      F
4          e        c      M
5          e        c      F

m = df['Gender'].eq('M')
df['new'] = np.where(m, m.groupby(df['Occupation']).transform('mean').mul(100), 0)
print (df)
  Occupation Emp_Code Gender        new
0          d        a      M  66.666667
1          d        a      F   0.000000
2          d        b      M  66.666667
3          e        b      F   0.000000
4          e        c      M  33.333333
5          e        c      F   0.000000
```

If want new DataFrame filled by normlize values one possible solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and `normalize` parameter:

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['Occupation'], df['Gender'],normalize='index')
print (df2)
Gender             F         M
Occupation                    
d           0.333333  0.666667
e           0.666667  0.333333
```

Comment: When I tried to add 'Emp_code' to `groupby` .. `df['new'] = np.where(m, m.groupby(df['Occupation','Emp_Code']).transform('mean').mul(100), 0)` I got this error `KeyError: ('Occupation', 'Emp_Code')`

Comment: Hey did you able see my post ?